# How can I add an App.xaml to a class library?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, app.xaml

I created a class library in C # and then added a WPF user control. However, I would still need the App.xaml, which is missing here, to add the resource dictionary. So the question is how can I add the associated App.xaml to my existing WPF user control in my class library.

Comment: Why do you think you need it? A UserControl library is not an application.

Comment: For Material Design I need the App.xaml to add the resources there

Comment: Put the resources in a seperate ResourceDictionary, that is added to the MergedDictionaries of the Resources of the UserControl. Or of course directly into UserControl.Resources, in case there is only a single one in the library.